# Server 2016 VM does not boot after hyper-v install

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, freeze, hyper-v, windows-server-2016

I am using VMWare Workstation 14, with Windows Server 2016 installed on it. A few weeks ago in my server class, we had an in class lab to setup a Nano Server. I successfully got that up and running and installed Hyper-V and loaded it into it. Started up, and signed in. Then two days later at class again, the VM just freezes at the windows logo with circling white dots.

I have installed multiple VMs trying to get it up and running. Always the same result. I have the virtualization enable in BIOS on my laptop.

I have a VM snapshot I just took before installing Hyper-V, installed the role, rebooted, and again, stops at the windows logo with circling dots.

I don't know where to check if there is an issue, or if something is configured incorrectly. I am just looking for some help and ideas on what I should check. I do also have the virtualization stuff within VMWare enabled under the properties for the VM.

System details:

Asus GL502VMZ
Version 10.0.17134 Build 17134
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz, 2808 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)
Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 16.0 GB
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 3GB

Comment: Same thing happens with Server 2016 Datacenter Core.

Comment: Voting co close. Off topic. Stackoverflow is about programming questions. Serverfault deals with business level (superuser.com private) system administration. This question is about professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration This question is more likely to get an answer on Server Fault.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried uninstalling the anti-virus? I was running into the same issue in my server class (Using VMware to run server 2016 which we where using to nest hyper-v)until a class mate said he didn't have the AV (we where looking for differences on why his worked and mind didn't). I removed my AV (was AVG) now the server no longer stalls at the boot screen.

Comment: I ended up reimaging my laptop. After doing so, the VM I stalls hyper v and boots without issue. No idea on that one.

Comment: Are you running a third party anti-virus? and if so is there no interference with the VM at all? only asking because that problem had my class stumped for a solid 3 days delaying future projects.

Answer (score -1):

Just my 2 cents that may help someone in the future.  I had the same issue on an HP Proliant ML310e that worked fine for the full install until enabling the Hyper-V role, then it would hang at the Windows icon screen with the swirling dots.  I was able to get past that by disabling [Intel VT-d](https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=mmr_kc-0121549) in the bios.  Not a particularly good solution, but it allowed the system to boot successfully and run normally.